# Не получается организовать поиск строки с помощью регулярного выражения с учетом регистра

Tags: php

суть задачи у меня такая хочу вывести: 
1) строку "Машина" если строка начинается со слова например "Машина"с учетом регистра символов;
2) строку "Машина" если строка заканчивается и  начинается словом "Машина"

```
<?php
// create a string
$string = 'Машинаlmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
$string2 = 'Машина Математика Машинаlmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
// try to match the beginning of the string
if(preg_match("/^Машина/", $string))
{
    // if it matches we echo this line
    echo 'Машина';
}
else
{
    // if no match is found echo this line
    echo 'Совпадений не найдено';
}
if(preg_match("/\bМашина\b/i", $string2))
{
    // if it matches we echo this line
    echo 'Машина';
}
else
{
    // if no match is found echo this line
    echo 'Совпадений не найдено';
}
?>
```

Comment: Буквально сегодня знаком с регулярными выражениями, буду рад за подсказки, гуглил аналогичные примеры, но похожего очень мало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно, речь идёт о данных в кодировке UTF-8, тогда для регулярки необходимо указывать модификатор `u` ([PCRE_UTF8](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)). По соображениям обратной совмести он по-умолчанию отключен.

```
preg_match("/^Машина/iu", $string)
```

С этим модификатором регулярка будет рассматривать как UTF8 строка и модификатор регистрозависимости `i` будет работать как ожидается.

Comment: Спасибо, действительно в кодировке проблема